# Exposing the node class and retain a reference to it in another class

Tags: java, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am looking for way to have my minecart objects act as a node so they can remove themselves from a list, but I fear that the current code design is causing troubles to allow this.

I think its because of the different types: `<T extends MineCart>` vs `<MineCart>`.
I am not looking for an answer on how to write the remove method, but rather look for a solution so a MineCart object can act like a node.
I would appreciate to get some advice on how to solve this problem.

Linkedlist (only the relevant part is shown)

```
public class MyCustomLinkedList<T extends MineCart> implements Iterable<T> {

    //... your typical list methods (e.g. add/remove etc)

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T item;
        private Node<T> prev, next;

        public Node(T item, Node<T> prev, Node<T> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

MineCart class (only the relevant part is shown)

```
public abstract class MineCart implements Comparable<MineCart> {
    public MineCart nextCart; 
    public MineCart prevCart;

    public MineCart getNextMineCart() {
       // and then do something like this:
       // return this.next;
       // or return nextCart;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is actually your question ? What is the relation between Wagon and MineCart ?

Comment: @Conffusion srry that was a typo, I fixed it. What my actual question is (simple version) I have a MineCart object --> now make it work like a node

Comment: Why do you need a Node class as MineCart has all the information (prev, next) ?

Comment: calling this.next in class MineCart doesnt work, also nextCart is null;

Answer (score 0):

To let a MineCart remove itself from the list:

```
public abstract class MineCart implements Comparable<MineCart> {
    public void remove() {
       prevCart.nextCart=nextCart;
    }
}
```

before:

```
[cart1] - [cart2] - [cart3]
```

cart2.remove()

after:

```
[cart1] - [cart3]  
[cart2]
```

Since MineCart is aware of its neighbours, you don't need a Node class.

Comment: My bad, I was not looking for a solution on how to write the remove method. I updated the question to make it a bit more clear.